An inequality about factorial function
Let $d,s,k$ be integers such that $d<s+2$, $s=o(k)$. For sufficiently large integer $k$, is the following inequality right?
$$\frac{(k-2d+1)^{k+s-d}}{(k-d)!\cdot (k-2)_s} \ge 1$$
We write $(k)_s = k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots (k-s+1)$.

Since $s = o(k)$ doesn't mean anything until there's a $k$, and since $k$ is sufficiently large anyway, can't $s = o(k)$ just be deleted?

Because $s$ is not a fixed constant, maybe $s=\lfloor \log k \rfloor$, i think $s=o(k)$ is necessary.

@LSpice no, not at all

Have you tried writing $(k-2)_s = \frac{(k-2)!}{(k-s-2)!}$ and using Stirling's approximation? All the factorials there go to infinity

Yes. It seems to be that if we have $(1-\frac{2s+2}{k-2})^{2s+2}\cdot e^{k-s-2} \ge 1$ then it is true.

@ZhukuiBai: Bernoulli's inequality will help.

It is nice. I seems to have an answer. I will add it.

Are $s$ and $d$ positive?

@Iosif Pinelis Yes, they are positive.

@mathworker21, re, but, aside from the solecism of writing $s = o(k)$ when there is no $k$ yet, what is the difference between "for every $d$, for every $s$ with $d < s + 2$, $s = o(k)$ [?], for every $k$ sufficiently large" and "for every $d$, for every $s$ with $d < s + 2$, for every $k$ sufficiently large [depending on $s$]"?  If it is preferred to emphasise explicitly that the sufficient largeness of $k$ depends on $s$, then $k = \omega(s)$ could be used just as well, or the quantifications over $s$ and $k$ could be switched.

@LSpice I agree. I think, though, the OP should have just started with "let $d,s,k$ be integers such that ...$.

$\newcommand\p\partial$Let us show that the inequality in question holds for all integers $k,s,d$ such that
\begin{equation}
    k\ge6s,\quad s\ge1,\quad 1\le d\le s+1. \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation}
That is, we are going to show that for such $k,s,d$ we have
\begin{equation}
    f(k,s,d):=\frac{(k-2 d+1)^{k+s-d}(k-s-2)! }{(k-d)!(k-2)!}\ge1. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation}
First, note that
\begin{equation}
    r(k,s,d):=\frac{f(k+1,s,d)}{f(k,s,d)}=R(k,s,d)p(k,s,d) \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    R(k,s,d):=e \frac{(k-2 d+2) (k-s-1)}{(k-1) (k-d+1)},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    p(k,s,d):=\left(1-\frac{1}{k-2 d+2}\right)^{d-k-s}/e
\end{equation}
It is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
    R(k,s,d)>1; \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation}
we are assuming conditions \eqref{10} throughout.
Next,
\begin{equation}
p_2(k,s,d):=(1 - 2 d + k)^2  (2 - 2 d + k)^2 \, \p_k^2 \ln p(k,s,d) \\ 
    =-4 d^2+d (2 k-4 s+9)+k (2 s-3)+3 s-4
\end{equation}
in concave in $d$, with $p_2(k,s,1)=k (2 s-1)-s+1\ge(2 s-1)-s+1>0$ and $p_2(k,s,s+1)=k (4 s-1)-8 s^2+1\ge 6s(4 s-1)-8 s^2+1=16 s^2-6 s+1>0$. So, $\p_k^2 \ln p(k,s,d)\ge0$ and hence $\ln p(k,s,d)$ is convex in $k$. Also, $\ln p(k,s,d)\to0$ as $k\to\infty$. So, $\ln p(k,s,d)\ge0$ and hence $p(k,s,d)\ge1$. So, by \eqref{30} and \eqref{40}, $r(k,s,d)>1$ and hence $f(k,s,d)$ is increasing in $k$. So, in view of \eqref{10}, it is enough to show that
\begin{equation}
    F(s,d):=f(6s,s,d)\ge1. \tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation}
Let now
\begin{equation}
    \rho(s,d):=\frac{F(s,d+1)}{F(s,d)}=
    (6s-2 d-1)^{7s-d-1} (6s-2 d+1)^{d-7 s} (6 s-d)  
\end{equation}
and then
\begin{align*}
    &\rho_2(s,d) \\
    &:=(6s-d)^2  (6s-2d+1)^2  (6s-2d-1)^2\,\p_d^2\ln\rho(s,d)  \\ 
    &=32 d^3 s-16 d^3-912 d^2 s^2+240 d^2 s+4 d^2+5760 d s^3 \\ 
    &-1152 d
   s^2-9936 s^4+1728 s^3-72 s^2-1, 
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{equation}
    \p_d^2 \rho_2(s,d)=96 d (2 s-1)-1824 s^2+480 s+8 \\ 
    \le 96 (s+1) (2 s-1)-1824 s^2+480 s+8 \\ 
    =-8 (11 - 72 s + 204 s^2)<0.
\end{equation}
So, $\rho_2(s,d)$ is concave in $d$, with $\rho_2(s,s+1)=-1609 - 8704 u - 17444 u^2 - 15392 u^3 - 5056 u^4<0$ and $\p_d\rho_2(s,s+1)=8 (266 + 985 u + 1218 u^2 + 504 u^3)>0$ with $u:=s-1\ge0$. So, $\rho_2(s,d)<0$ and hence $\ln\rho(s,d)$ is concave in $d$.
Next,
\begin{equation}
    \rho_1(s):=\p_d\ln\rho(s,d)|_{d=1}=
    \frac{5-22 s}{12 s (3 s-2)+3}-2 \coth ^{-1}(2-6 s)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \rho'_1(s)=\frac{40 s^2-8 s+2}{\left(12 s^2-8 s+1\right)^2}>0
\end{equation}
and $\rho_1(\infty-)=0$. So, $\rho_1(s)<0$. So, $\rho(s,d)$ is decreasing in $d$.
Next,
\begin{equation}
    \p_s^2\ln\rho(s,1)=-\frac{8 (4 s+1)}{(4 s (3 s-2)+1)^2}<0,
\end{equation}
so that $\ln\rho(s,1)$ is concave in $s$. Also, $\ln\rho(\infty-,1)=-7/3<0$. So, $\rho(s,1)<1$.
So, $F(s,d)$ is decreasing in $d$. So, it is enough to show that
\begin{equation}
h(s):=  F(s,s+1)\ge1. \tag{60}\label{60}
\end{equation}
Consider
\begin{equation}
    \tau(s):=\frac{h(s+1)}{h(s)}. 
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
    \tau''(s)\,(s^2  (1 + 2 s)^2  (1 + 3 s)^2  (2 + 3 s)^2  (-1 + 4 s)^2  (3 + 
    4 s)^2  (-1 + 5 s)^2  (4 + 5 s)^2  (-1 + 6 s)^2  (1 + 6 s)^2)
\end{equation}
is a polynomial in $u:=s-1$ with all coefficients $\le0$. So, $\tau(s)$ is concave in $s$, with $\tau(1)>23>1$ and $\tau(\infty-)>35>1$. So, $\tau(s)>1$. So, $h(s)$ is increasing in $s$, from $h(1)=81/32>1$. So, $h(s)>1$. $\quad\Box$.

This is quite the solution...

Thanks a lot! But i do not see that why "hence $\ln p(k,s,d)$ is convex in $k$. Also, $\ln p(k,s,d)\to0$ as $k\to\infty$. So, $\ln p(k,s,d)\ge0$", why not $\ln p(k,s,d)\le 0$?

@ZhukuiBai : Any convex function $g$ with $g(\infty-)=0$ is $\ge0$. Indeed, suppose the contrary: $g(x)<0$ for some real $x$. Since $g(\infty-)=0$, there is some real $y>x$ such that $g(y)>g(x)$. Then, by the convexity of $g$, for real $t>y$ we have $g(t)\ge g(y)+\dfrac{t-y}{y-x},(g(y)-g(x))\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$, so that  $0=g(\infty-)=\infty$, a contradiction.

Yes. You are right.
